# Using MediaPlayer to listen a web radio?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying implement the MediaPlayer of Android to listen a stream radio web. To do it I did extends MediaPlayer but when I try start the player has throws an exception. I think that the stream server is a icecast and works with ogg. Here the URL of stream: http://hdmediaserver2.info:8144/live

How could I do it ?

```
public class CustomMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer{
    private static CustomMediaPlayer INSTANCE = null;

    private boolean isPause = false;

    public boolean isPause() {
        return isPause;
    }

    public void setPause(boolean isPause) {
        this.isPause = isPause;
    }

    private CustomMediaPlayer() {}

    public static CustomMediaPlayer getInstance(
            OnCompletionListener onCompeletionListener) {
        if (null == INSTANCE) {
            INSTANCE = new CustomMediaPlayer();
        }
        INSTANCE.setOnCompletionListener(onCompeletionListener);
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        isPause = false;
        super.reset();
    }

    public void play() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        if (!isPause) {
            super.prepare();
        }
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws IllegalStateException {
        isPause = false;
        super.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() throws IllegalStateException {
        isPause = true;
        super.pause();
    }

    public void previousOrNext() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        isPause = false;
        play();
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class RadioFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName() + "->";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageButton btPlay;
    private ImageButton btStop;
    private ImageButton btVolume;

    //media player
    private final MediaPlayer MP = CustomMediaPlayer.getInstance(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_frag, container, false);

        btPlay = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
        btStop = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        btVolume = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btVolume);

        //listeners
        btPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        btStop.setOnClickListener(this);
        btVolume.setOnClickListener(this);

        return  view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btPlay){
            progressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog().getCustomProgress(null, getView().getContext());
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            try {
                MP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                MP.setDataSource("http://hdmediaserver2.info:8144/live.m3u");

                MP.setOnErrorListener(this);
                MP.setOnPreparedListener(this);

                MP.setVolume((float) 50 / 100, (float) 50 / 100);
                MP.setLooping(false);
                MP.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("AUDIOHTTPPLAYER", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        MP.start();
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
05-07 11:43:14.335    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
05-07 11:43:14.335    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
05-07 11:43:14.405    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setVolume: left 0.500000  right 0.500000
05-07 11:43:14.405    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setVolume(0.500000, 0.500000)
05-07 11:43:14.410    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setLooping: 0
05-07 11:43:14.410    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setLooping
05-07 11:43:14.410    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
05-07 11:43:14.410    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
05-07 11:43:14.640    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-07 11:43:14.640    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-07 11:43:14.640    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
05-07 11:43:14.645    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
05-07 11:43:16.000    1710-1721/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
05-07 11:43:16.000    1710-1721/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1004)
05-07 11:43:16.000    1710-1721/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
05-07 11:43:16.010    1710-1721/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
05-07 11:43:16.015    1710-1710/br.com.williarts.radios.upacarai E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1004)
```

Comment: Open the m3u and read the stream url. -> http://hdmediaserver2.info:8144/live. As it seems to be an icecast2 server, I think you can just open the stream.

Comment: @se_bastiaan how I can do this ?

Comment: Is this the full stack trace?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan edited post ! ..I think that the stream server is a icecast and works with ogg. Here the URL of stream: http://hdmediaserver2.info:8144/live

Comment: Try setDataSource("http://hdmediaserver2.info:8144/live") and check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9385345/1074080

Comment: @se_bastiaan if I add this link `http://hdmediaserver2.info:8144/live` directly doesn't works. And if I add this same link in web browser does  start a infinity download and does not play sounds. Are you know what could this problem ? Please copy the link and paste in your browser to you understand what I said.

Comment: Have you solved this?